# Dictionary like operations on string in python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a string `product: Netatalk version: 2.2.0 extrainfo: name: WNDR4500; protocol 3.3 ostype: Unix` where I would like to be able to dictionary-like operations on, to get things like product, version, etc. What would be the best way to do these kind of operations? I know I can solve this with splits and similar things, but that really is not a "beautiful" way of coding. Any suggestions?

Comment: Indeed. It would be parse-able as in "extrainfo: name: is a subset(sub dict) because it has two :'s, but indeed, it's pretty vague... Sadly, this is all i have to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried writing a recursive dict-parser and it was kicking my butt until I thought *you know, it would be a lot easier if I did this backwards...* Voila!

```
import re

def make_dict(s):
    # break into list of keys and values
    chunks = re.split("\s*(\w+\:)\s*", s)
    res = {}
    # work backwards in value,key pairs
    args = [reversed(chunks)] * 2
    for value,key in zip(*args):
        key = key.rstrip(':')
        if value:
            # add to current result-dict
            res[key] = value
        else:
            # start a higher-level result-dict
            res = {key: res}
    return res
```

then

```
>>> make_dict("product: Netatalk version: 2.2.0 extrainfo: name: WNDR4500; protocol 3.3 ostype: Unix")
{'extrainfo': {'ostype': 'Unix', 'name': 'WNDR4500; protocol 3.3'},
 'version': '2.2.0',
 'product': 'Netatalk'}
```

Comment: That's also a pretty clever way, and it solves the issue with the sub dictionary! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it on my own:

```
def product(banner):
  if banner:
    p=re.search('(product:).([^\s]+)', banner)
    return p.group(2)
  else:
    return "unknown"
```

This will return the "product", and can be adapted if I need something else.